# Error C++: 'BIO_ADDR' does not name a type

Tags: c++, ssl, makefile, openssl, include

I'm a C++ developer. I'm using OpenSSL to make my data secure.

In this code:

```cpp
#include <openssl/bio.h>

typedef struct contextt {
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  SSL *ssl;        
  HMAC_CTX *cookie_hmac;
  BIO_METHOD *meth;
  BIO_ADDR *bio_addr;
} contextt;
```

I get these errors:

```
error: 'BIO_ADDR' does not name a type
error: 'BIO_set_init' was not declared in this scope
error: 'BIO_set_data' was not declared in this scope
```

`BIO_ADDR` is declared in `bio.h` with `BIO_set_init()`, and `openssl/bio.h` is under `/usr/include`.

I included the `bio.h` in the code, and I gave the path, but I don't know what the real problem is.

I think maybe a problem in the library or the makefile, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: *BIO_ADDR is declared in bio.h...* [Are you sure about that](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/crypto/bio/bio.h)?  There are multiple versions of OpenSSL.

Comment: yes @AndrewHenle i verified it many times, it is declared either then BIO_METHOD, the code see BIO_METHOD and it cant see BIO_ADDR i don't know why.

Comment: @MYG11 What version of the OpenSSL SDK are you using? `BIO_ADDR` doesn't exist in OpenSSL 1.0.2, it was added in 1.1.x

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.1s, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MYG11 `BIO_ADDR`, `BIO_set_init()`, and `BIO_set_data()` definitely exist in that version: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1s/include/openssl/bio.h